# How to insert the sum of two tables in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I create the following tables:

```
create table AandB (
        code              varchar(9),
        total             number,
        CONSTRAINT pk_code PRIMARY KEY (code)
);

create table A (
        codeA              varchar(9),
        numberA              number,
        CONSTRAINT pk_codeA PRIMARY KEY (codeA)
);

create table B (
        codeB              varchar(9),
        numberB            number,
        CONSTRAINT pk_codeB PRIMARY KEY (codeB)
);
```

I inserted the following datas:

```
insert into AandB(code) values('0x1');
insert into AandB(code) values('0x2');
insert into AandB(code) values('0x3');

insert into A(codeA, numberA) values('0x1',5);
insert into A(codeA, numberA) values('0x2',6);
insert into A(codeA, numberA) values('0x3',1);

insert into B(codeB, numberB) values('0x1',8);
insert into B(codeB, numberB) values('0x2',10);
insert into B(codeB, numberB) values('0x3',12);
```

The question is: how to insert numberA+numberB in the column "total" of the table "AandB", ie:

> 0X1 = 13
>
> 0X2 = 16
>
> 0X3 = 13

Thanks for any suggestions or answers, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just update the `AandB` table according to a join between `A` and `B`

```
UPDATE AandB ab
SET ab.total = (SELECT a.numberA + b.numberB
                FROM A
                INNER JOIN B
                 ON(a.codeA = b.codeB)
                WHERE a.codeA = ab.code)
```

If `A` and `B` table won't necessarily contain all of `AandB` codes , that you should add a where clause to filter them:

```
UPDATE AandB ab
SET ab.total = (SELECT a.numberA + b.numberB
                FROM A
                INNER JOIN B
                 ON(a.codeA = b.codeB)
                WHERE a.codeA = ab.code)
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM A
             INNER JOIN B
              ON(a.codeA = b.codeB)
             WHERE a.codeA = ab.code)
```